# Postfix auth issue

Tags: postfix, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm currently facing auth issue.
When I'm trying to auth via telnet, I face an issue

```
"535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure"
```

I use password and login the same, as I use for login in my server, but It says, that login information is wrong.

Here is my telnet log:

```
telnet ....... 25
Trying ...........
Connected to .........
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ..........com ESMTP Postfix 
EHLO local.domain.name 
250-...........com 
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth login
```

Than I code my login and password in base64 and get error.

Here is my config file:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = .........
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = /etc/postfix/local-host-names
relayhost =
#mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes

home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtusertable
```

What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Postfix SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) first. You are missing this:

> Postfix does not implement SASL itself, but instead uses existing
> implementations as building blocks. This means that some SASL-related
> configuration files will belong to Postfix, while other configuration
> files belong to the specific SASL implementation that Postfix will
> use. This document covers both the Postfix and non-Postfix
> configuration.
>
> Successful authentication in the Postfix SMTP server requires a
> functional SASL framework. Configuring SASL should therefore always be
> the first step, before configuring Postfix.

But that's only the beginning. You probably don't actually want to allow plain text authentication as you are currently doing, but use [`STARTTLS`](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html), instead. Then, authenticated users usually use *submission* on port `587` as port `25` is generally blocked on Internet connections that aren't intended for mail servers. [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) how-to from Dovecot wiki puts most of this nicely together with clear configuration examples.